# Join entity in many to many not being persisted after applying "@Transient" to the corresponding entities and the join entity

Tags: java, hibernate, join, many-to-many, entity

the main idea of my setup is to manage the many to many relationship via repositories. That is why, in the following setup, all the relations are annotated as `@Transient`, since those sets should only be populated "manually", instead of letting Hibernate do that.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "house")
public class House {
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Transient
    private Set<Owner> owners;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner {
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Transient
    private Set<House> houses;
}

public class HouseIdOwnerId implements Serializable {
    private long houseId;
    private long ownerId;

    public HouseIdOwnerId(final long houseId, final long ownerId) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) { /* ... */ }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() { /* ... */ }
}

@Entity
@IdClass(HouseIdOwnerId.class)
@Table(name = "house_owner")
public class HouseOwner{
    @Column(name = "house_id")
    @Id
    private long houseId;

    @Column(name = "owner_id")
    @Id
    private long ownerId;

    @Transient
    private House house;

    @Transient
    private Owner owner;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    public HouseOwner(final House house, final Owner owner) {
        this.houseId = house.getId();
        this.house = house;

        this.ownerId = owner.getId();
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) { /* ... */ }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() { /* ... */ } 
}
```

As one would expect, when trying to persist the join entity, since its properties are marked as `@Transient`, nothing happens:

```java
@Test
void testInsertRelated() {
    // ...
    this.entityManager.persist(house);
    this.entityManager.persist(owner);
    this.entityManager.persist(owner2);

    final HouseOwner ho = new HouseOwner(house, owner);
    final HouseOwner ho2 = new HouseOwner(house, owner2);

    this.entityManager.persist(ho);
    this.entityManager.persist(ho2);
}
```

The reason I didn't do `@OneToMany` relationships in the dependent entities is because they would end up with ugly `Set<HouseOwner> houses` and `Set<HouseOwner> owners` properties, that of course would get ignored when persisting the main entities.

So, imagine that a request comes which creates a new house that is going to get associated with multiple owners. You would need to, somehow, map the incoming owner IDs to multiple `HouseOwner` objects, so these need some way of being created without the `House` part, because it is not yet created. Therefore, you end up with an ugly `HouseOwner` object.

---

Summarizing, I think I am mixing up concepts here. However, is it possible to do what I am trying above? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly. Why don't you use many-to-many relationships? Is it a design choice? Let me try to answer in different flavors.

### Using many-to-many relationships

When using the 'many-to-many' relationships, you shouldn't create entity classes for join tables. In your example, the class *HouseOwner* shouldn't be coded. Your model contains two entities: *House* and *Owner*. The way they interact with each other is through a many-to-many relationship. Once you define this relationship in your mappings, the JPA engine will derive the join table automatically (you can use `@JoinTable` mapping if the defaults doesn't fit you). The code would look like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "house")
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "house_owner", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "house_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id"))
    private Set<Owner> owners;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "owners") /* you must elect a relationship owner */
    private Set<House> houses;
}
```

And that's all you need to define your entities and their relationships. You can see the JPA is expecting the existence of a third table by enabling the `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action` property in your `persistence.xml`. Sniffing the created script, you would see something like this:

```sql
create table house (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id));
create table house_owner (house_id bigint not null, owner_id bigint not null, primary key (house_id, owner_id));
create table owner (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id));
alter table if exists house_owner add constraint FK96rb7vss0wg6qgwkbfmt4iw9w foreign key (owner_id) references owner;
alter table if exists house_owner add constraint FKcb77jw3le78e333bx246ln3ap foreign key (house_id) references house;
```

### Using one-to-many relationships

One issue with the previous approach, as you mentioned in your comment, is that it isn't possible to map the `LocalDateTime createdAt` field in the **house_owner** join table. One way around this problem is to use one-to-many mappings on `House` and `Owner` entities. The code would look like this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "house")
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "house")
    private Set<HouseOwner> owners;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private Set<HouseOwner> houses;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "house_owner")
public public class HouseOwner {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "house_id")
    private House house;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private Owner owner;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}
```

Again, enabling the `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action` property and looking at the generated script, you'll see:

```
create table house (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id));
create table house_owner (createdAt timestamp(6), house_id bigint not null, owner_id bigint not null, primary key (house_id, owner_id));
create table owner (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id));
alter table if exists house_owner add constraint FKcb77jw3le78e333bx246ln3ap foreign key (house_id) references house;
alter table if exists house_owner add constraint FK96rb7vss0wg6qgwkbfmt4iw9w foreign key (owner_id) references owner;
```

It's pretty much the same output as the previous example! But, this way, you have more control over the *house_owner* table.

### Using transient annotations

If yet you want to use `@Transient` in your modeling, I can only imagine that you don't want the JPA engine doing the hard work for you. But, if you must, you can do the following:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "house")
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Transient
    private Set<Owner> owners;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Transient
    private Set<House> houses;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "house_owner")
public class HouseOwner {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "house_id")
    private long houseId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "owner_id")
    private long ownerId;

    @Transient
    private House house;
    @Transient
    private Owner owner;
}
```

Once more, sniffing the created script by enabling `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action` property, you would see something like this:

```
create table house (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id));
create table house_owner (owner_id bigint not null, house_id bigint not null, primary key (house_id, owner_id));
create table owner (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id));
```

As you can see, the same three tables - but this time without the foreign keys. This means that JPA will ignore any relationship between your entities.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.The first approach has the problem of not being able to specify a `@CreationTimestamp` for the `createdAt` property in the join table I defined in my question. I was even thinking that ,slightly different from the second approach that you mention, I could even spare the join entity entirely, since I will be using custom queries to insert the other related entities in the database... so I would probably not use `entity.manager.persist(joinEntity)`, but rather a native query to insert stuff... What do you think?

Comment: @MikelAlejoBR Did you consider using ValueObjects as `@Embeddable`? Maybe you can create some kind of a log class (with the owner_id, buyingDate, sellingDate, etc) and map it as `@ElementCollection` in the `House` class. I have a [repository](https://github.com/mauriciobuffon/jakartaee-poc) where I play along with some JPA concepts. Luckily, it can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. For some unrelated reasons I can't take a deep look now at the resource you shared with me, but after a quick glance I saw a few bits that seem that will be useful when I come back to this. In the meantime, I will accept your answer because I appreciate the time and effort you've put into giving me support on this matter. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MikelAlejoBR Yesterday, researching for a similar situation, I've come across the *one-to-many* solution. I've updated the answer with this possibility. Btw, I noticed I didn't answer the question you asked in the first comment. In my time using JPA, I mostly used JPQL to query data, not to change it - I remember one exception using JPQL to alter data and it was made for bulk updates. The way I see it, if you find yourself writing a lot of SQL for data control, you might want to stop using JPA and start using just JDBC.